# Karma - run tests on previously preprocessed files

Tags: javascript, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

Would it be possible in any way, to run Karma/Jasmine tests in two-step approach:

1. First step preprocesses all application files (Babel, Webpack, coverage, source maps, etc.) and stores the preprocessed output.
2. Second step runs actual (Jasmine) tests on files already preprocessed in first step.

?

This way we could preprocess all application code once and run second step as many times as we want (of course assuming that we don't change application code after running step 1).

Edit:
Some more details:

- app code is divided into modules: common, moduleA, moduleB, ...
- there is a single `karma.conf.js` with preprocessors set up to handle entire code base
- Grunt is used to run karma tests - there are separate tasks to run tests only for given module (given Grunt task adjusts `files` section of Karma config to load only test specs for module that is to be tested)
- On CI we test each module separately - running all tests in one go crashes the browser (due to excessive memory use - we've had little success in fixing this). So Karma runs `n` times (`n` is number of modules) preprocessing entire code base each time and running tests only for module that's currently being tested.
- Since actual code (neither app or specs) does not change while modules are being tested one-by-one our idea was to tell Karma to only preprocess entire code base at first. Afterwards we could run Karma on each module using the previously preprocessed code. This should be much faster than what we currently have.

By the way, this is an Angular app. Tests are based on Jasmine and use ngDescribe.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". The question is super vague by the way.

Comment: @Wilmer, Yes, the question is very general. Is actual answer/solution more of a hack or something that Karma actually supports? Would you need any more details to provide  some guidance?

Comment: No hack needed. Your first step is just a build step where Karma is in no way involved. However, make sure you don't run any optimization (minification, uglyfication) on your pre-processing which will prevent you from running your second step.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I assumed that all preprocessing will be done by Karma plugins. But I guess that it can indeed be done outside of Karma.
Thank you very much for the tip.